# Cocoon translate from slim to erb guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

Sorry for my noob questions. I use Simple_Form and ERB.HTML for my views. Actually try to implement Cocoon and the guide use SLIM. someone could help me? :)

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

In our projects/_form partial we'd write:

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :description
  %h3 Tasks
  #tasks
    = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
     = render 'task_fields', :f => task
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks
  = f.submit
```

In our _task_fields partial we write:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :done, :as => :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277482/how-can-i-convert-html-slim-to-html-erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will by like this. In the `_form` partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <h3>Tasks</h3>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
    <%= render 'task_fields', :f => task %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Task', f, :tasks %>
  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And in the partial `_task_fields`:

```
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :done, :as => :boolean %>
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove task", f %>
```

**Note:**

The above example is of [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem and not of default rails `form_for`. So install the gem before using this.

And to use cocoon gem do take care of the partial naming i.e., for example `_task_fields`. If you want to provide any other name then there are options for it given in the gem documentation. Or by default it will search for that name.