# Converting Slim to HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to build a web app using Ruby on rails, but I have a code in slim instead of HTML file(index.html.erb). How I can covert the slim code to HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert html.slim to html.erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277482/how-can-i-convert-html-slim-to-html-erb)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy. If you want to use an online tool there are plenty available online with a simple google search. If you'd like to convert an actual file this script seems to do the job well enough. https://gist.github.com/keewon/66627851aeb662b12f54